# Actionscript SQLite Insert Statements in a transaction

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sqlite, actionscript, transactions

I'm trying to get my head around how to do a SQLite bulk insert using transactions in Flex / Actionscript 3 (using Adobe Air 2).  This works, but it doesn't make sense to re-create a new SQLStatement in the loop:

```
private function onAddBulkContacts():void {
_responder = new Responder(resultEventHandler, errorEventHandler);
contacts_db.connection.begin(null, _responder);
var statement:SQLStatement;

for (var i:uint=0; i<parseInt(bulkAdd.numberToAdd.text); i++) {
 statement  = new SQLStatement();
statement.sqlConnection = contacts_db.connection;
statement.text ="INSERT INTO contacts ('name', 'lastname') VALUES (@NAME, @LASTNAME)";

statement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, function(event:Event):void {
trace('statement error');});
statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, function(event:Event):void { trace('result'); });
    statement.parameters['@NAME'] = "Name " + i.toString();
    statement.parameters['@LASTNAME'] = "LastName " + i.toString();
    statement.execute();   
}
contacts_db.connection.commit();
}
```

What I want to do is create the SQLStatement once, let it compile, then just pass in new arguments within the loop, the commit it at the end, e.g.

```
private function onAddBulkContacts():void {
_responder = new Responder(resultEventHandler, errorEventHandler);
contacts_db.connection.begin(null, _responder);
var statement:SQLStatement;

statement  = new SQLStatement();
statement.sqlConnection = contacts_db.connection;
statement.text ="INSERT INTO contacts ('name', 'lastname') VALUES (@NAME, @LASTNAME)";

statement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, function(event:Event):void {
trace('statement error');});
statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, function(event:Event):void { trace('result'); });

for (var i:uint=0; i<parseInt(bulkAdd.numberToAdd.text); i++) {
    statement.parameters['@NAME'] = "Name " + i.toString();
    statement.parameters['@LASTNAME'] = "LastName " + i.toString();
    statement.execute();   
}
contacts_db.connection.commit();
}
```

But the latter code throw an error saying that it can't execute the second time through, since the statement itself is still executing (and I believe will be in that state until the commit).  I guess I can understand that the statements get added to the execution queue, but it doesn't make sense that I have to add the SQL text within the loop, exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I've spent way too long hacking and reading trying to figure out what the proper sequence is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have all your inserts in one statement but with incremental parameters? ie. `@NAME1`, `@NAME2`, etc

Comment: Does SQLite not support "INSERT into Contacts (Name, LastName) VALUES ('Frank', 'Furter'), ('Jack', 'Horner'), ('Bo', 'Peep')" ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done bulk inserts in AIR, but typically one creates the statement outside the loop, initiates the transaction; then with each iteration of the loop binds new parameter values and executes the statement; then outside the loop, commit.

Is the database opened in synchronous or asynchronous mode?

In asynch mode:

`... the simplest way to organize the application to ensure that the operations are executed properly is to create a method that’s registered as a listener for the begin event. The code to call the SQLStatement.execute() method is placed within that listener method.`  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d2b.html

You could also try getting the next set of values to be bound to the statement parameters using the array.shift() method rather than in a loop; the array.shift() method would be invoked in the result handler; when the array is empty you'd commit; your error handler would issue a rollback.